# What happened to the Mugmar?

Tags: minhag, history, blessing, mishna, tractate-brachot

In Brochos Perek 6, Mishna 6 the *Mugmar* is mentioned in the context of who makes the *Brocha* for it.  Commentaries explain that it is some sort of incense that was smelled after a meal.

It would seem that this custom has been lost to the ages.  Does anyone know if it is done anywhere today in the Jewish world?  Maybe some Sefardim still perform this custom?  And if it has indeed disappeared, does anyone know why?

Comment: I wonder whether it was a custom of Jews more than of others.